# get text PHP5 don't work on debian

Tags: php, debian, locale, gettext

I'm developing a web site which use gettext. Every thing work great in local. But today I've upload my web site on my production server and gettext don't want to work anymore. 
The language I'd like to use are fr_FR and en_US.
gettext translate my text if I display my web site in french but nothing happen for the english.

When I execute **locale -a** on my debian server, I get:

```
C
fr_FR.utf8
POSIX
```

I'm french so I think every thing is normal. But when I do: **locale-gen en_US** or **locale-gen en_US.UTF-8** and then **locale -a** again, nothing change. ! Is that normal ?

Here is a sample of PHP code just in case. But since gettext work for the french language, I believe the problem is not here.

```
$langage = 'en_US.utf8';
putenv("LC_ALL=$langage"); 
setlocale(LC_ALL, $langage); 

$languageFileName = "default"; // locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/default.mo
bindtextdomain($languageFileName, PATH.'/locale'); 
bind_textdomain_codeset($languageFileName, 'UTF-8');
textdomain($languageFileName);
```

Thanks a lot in advance for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I've find the solution to my problem. I've edited the file **/etc/locale.gen** and uncomment the language I'd like to use with gettext. Then I've run **locale-gen**. That's it !

Still don't understand why **locale-gen en_US.UTF-8** didn't do the same thing. 
I'm using debian 6 Squeeze.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem: the `en_US` locale was missing, and `locale-gen en_US.UTF-8` worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to on the php extension `php_gettext`.

Comment: Can you give me more detail ? In my phpinfo, I have: GetText Support -> enabled. Is that what you mean ?